# Translating a union type subset from data.frame to data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to translate a subsetting from data.frame to `data.table` in order to improve the performance of my code. But I am completely new to `data.table`. What is the equivalent in `data.table` types of this subsetting statment?

```
for(ii in 1:nplayer)
   {
   subgame<-subset(game, game$playerA == player[ii] | game$playerB == player[ii])
   players[ii,4]<-nrow(subgame)
   }
```

I have defined a new `data.table` `gameDT` in this way

```
  gameDT<-data.table(game)
  setkey(gameDT,playerA,playerB)
```

output of dput

```
  >dput(game[1:2,])
   structure(list(country = c("New Zealand", "Australia"), tournament = c("WTA Auckland 2012", 
   "WTA Brisbane 2012"), date = c("2011-12-31 00:00:00", "2011-12-30 00:15:00"
   ), playerA = c("Schoofs B.", "Lucic M."), playerB = c("Puig M.", 
   "Tsurenko L."), resultA = c(1L, 1L), resultB = c(2L, 2L), oddA = c("1.8", 
   "2.17"), oddB = c("1.9", "1.57"), N = c(4L, 3L), Weight = c(1, 
   0.973608997871031)), .Names = c("country", "tournament", "date", 
   "playerA", "playerB", "resultA", "resultB", "oddA", "oddB", "N", 
   "Weight"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you dput your dataset or subset of it (e.g. dput(game[1:20,]) )?

Comment: The subset syntax in `data.table` is just `dt[playerA == "a" | playerB == "a"]`

Answer (score 1):

You could think about using `lapply` if this isn't just an exercise to learn `data.table`

I think the example below is comparable to what you are trying to do and you see a pretty decent speedup by using `lapply`:

```
set.seed(123)
library(microbenchmark)

game = data.frame(runif(1:50) , playerA = sample(letters[1:5], 50, replace = T), playerB = sample(letters[1:5], 50, replace = T))

player <- union(game$playerA, game$playerB)
nplayer <-  length(player)
players <- matrix(player, nrow = nplayer, ncol = 2) 

op  <- microbenchmark(
  LAPPLY = {counts <- lapply(1:nplayer, 
                             function(i) sum(game$playerA == player[i] | game$playerB == player[i]))
            names(counts) <- player }, 
  ORIG = {
      for(ii in 1:nplayer)
        {
          subgame<-subset(game, game$playerA == player[ii] | game$playerB == player[ii])
          players[ii,2]<-nrow(subgame)
        }},
  times = 1000)

op

#Unit: microseconds
#   expr     min       lq   median        uq       max neval
# LAPPLY 236.493 251.9985  259.095  269.3205  8323.701  1000
#   ORIG 938.194 981.9060 1002.880 1036.6705 61095.935  1000

unlist(counts)

# a  c  d  b  e 
#19 17 20 20 15 

players

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "a"  "19"
#[2,] "c"  "17"
#[3,] "d"  "20"
#[4,] "b"  "20"
#[5,] "e"  "15"
```

Comment: can you explain me better the meaning of this line please: `names(counts) <- player`

Comment: It names the elements in the list `counts`. Would be the same as `names(counts) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")` in this case.